# Are all files and folders of my site with data will be there in the AWS image which i created from an instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

My site is hosted on AWS Ubuntu instance. i wanted to create an image of that instance. 
All files and folders of my site with data will be there in the image?

Comment: Thanks a lot John Rotenstein, appreciate with your response and actually it solved my problem. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create an **Amazon Machine Image (AMI)** of an Amazon EC2 instance, then the AMI will contain a **complete copy of the disk volumes** associated with that instance.

You can then **launch new instances from that AMI**. The new instances will contain an exact copy of the AMI when they launch.

See: [Amazon Machine Images (AMI) - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AMIs.html)